# Find the Highest Sum in a Combination of Numbers

Tags: python, algorithm, combinations, python-itertools

Lets say I have this:

```
1A=6 2A=4.5  3A=6

1B=7 2B=6    3B=7.5

1C=6 2C=6.75 3C=9
```

I want to find the combination of numbers that yields the highest sum. None of the numbers before the letters can be used more than once and none of the letters after the numbers can be used more than once. eg. `1A+2B+3C, 1C+2B+3A` are valid. `1A+1B+2B,3A+2B+3B,1A+2A+3A` are invalid.

In this case the highest sum is `1A+2B+3C=21`. How would I find this result and combination using python?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you could tell us what you've tried and how it didn't work for you, we might be able to help resolve your difficulty.

Comment: isn't the highest combination actually `1B + 2C + 3C = 22.75`?

Comment: edited. sry about the confusion. I have tried a few things using the itertools.combination method from other SO links. I am still trying to wrap my head around it

Comment: does method efficiency matter? With issues like this, knowing if this is your actual data or not is important, because you can easily use some iteration tricks, but if you have a lot more values, that will be very innefficient

Comment: the arrays will range from 3x3 to 8x8. efficiency is not a issue

Comment: The efficient algorithm to solve this problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, python has libraries that will do this for you. See here: [Munkres](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/munkres/1.0.5.4#downloads)

Answer (score 4):

<s>For each of the entries with the same numeric prefix, find the maximum among them. Then sum up all those maximum values, and you will get the maximum sum with the given restriction.</s>

If the numbers and the letters must be unique, then it becomes a problem that can be solved with [Hungarian algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm).

> The Hungarian method is a combinatorial optimization algorithm that solves the [assignment problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem) in polynomial time `[...]`

From the description of [assignment problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem):

> The assignment problem is one of the fundamental combinatorial optimization problems in the branch of optimization or operations research in mathematics. It consists of finding a maximum weight [matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)) in a weighted bipartite graph.
>
> In its most general form, the problem is as follows:
>
> > There are a number of agents and a number of tasks. Any agent can be assigned to perform any task, incurring some cost that may vary depending on the agent-task assignment. It is required to perform all tasks by assigning exactly one agent to each task and exactly one task to each agent in such a way that the total cost of the assignment is minimized.

Comment: Wrong wrong wrong.  Eg for the example numbers that method adds up the invalid combination 1B=7, 2C=6.75, 3C=9,

Comment: @jwpat7: My answer is before the clarification. Check the revision history.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a python guy, so the following code might seem not that "python style", but the algorithm should be ok.

```
#test input. the matrix can be any n * n size.
matrix = [[6,7,6],[4.5,6,6.75],[6,7.5,9]]

#assistant array to track which numbers we have already used.
#check[i] = 1 if i has been used
check = [0]* len(matrix)

#max sum
max_sum = 0

def getMax(matrix,check,row,curr_sum):
    global max_sum
    #base case, we have reached the last letter.
    #check to see if this combination is max
    if(row==len(matrix)-1):
        for i in range(len(check)):
            if(check[i]==0 and (matrix[row][i]+curr_sum)>max_sum):
                max_sum = matrix[row][i]+curr_sum
    #recursive case, pick the current available number, go to next letter.
    else:
        for i in range(len(check)):
            if(check[i]==0):
                check[i]=1
                getMax(matrix,check,row+1,curr_sum+matrix[row][i])
                check[i]=0

getMax(matrix,check,0,0)

print max_sum
```

Note that it's a sort of brute force algorithm using recursion. In terms of time-complexity, better algorithm (e.g. dynamic programming approach) exists. You can add cache to the method to improve efficiency.

Also, if you want to know the combination, we need extra efforts to track the combination. (e.g. using another matrix to record)

Comment: This is valid for a square matrix. In this case it is 3x3. It crashes for an un-even matrix. How would this be modified if matrix = [[5,2,3],[6,7,6],[4.5,6,6.75],[6,7.5,9]]

Comment: Never mind got it. I zero padded the matrix to make it square and got the result i was looking for. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with:

```
l1 = [6, 7, 6]
l2 = [4.5, 6, 6.75]
l3 = [6, 7.5, 9]

map(max, [l1, l2, l3])
```

Comment: That doesn't work! It returns a list of the max of each of them, but that wont necessarily follow the criteria and, infact, it does not. this returns `[7, 6.75, 9]`, which is not allowed because 6.75 and 9 are both in the same column

Comment: @RyanSaxe This question was edited after I answered it to change the rules (it originally said that only the numbers couldn't be repeated, and even gave multiple examples of repeated letters, like 1A, 2A, 3A, that were supposedly legal).